# Why does matching on the result of `find_one` return an Option instead of the expected type?

Tags: rust, match

I'm trying to use the `.get` method on a BSON `OrderedDocument` that I'm retrieving from a MongoDB query. To handle any errors from the query I use a `match` operator on the query.

```
let id: String = "example".to_string();

let doc = match db.media.find_one(
    Some(doc! {
        "id" : id
    }),
    None,
) {
    Ok(c) => c,
    Err(e) => {
        // do stuff with the error
        return;
    }
};

println!("{:?}", doc.get("field"));
```

This returns an error for the last line:

> error[E0599]: no method named `get` found for type `std::option::Option<bson::ordered::OrderedDocument>` in the current scope

This must mean that the type returned from a `match` operation is an `Option`, not an `OrderedDocument` as I expected. Why is the `c` variable returned (in the example above) of type `Option` instead of the query's BSON document type, and how can I get the required type returned from a `match`? Or is this the wrong way of going about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type returned from a `match` operation is whatever you put in it. In this case, the type is that of `c`.

[`find_one`](https://docs.rs/mongodb/0.3.12/mongodb/coll/struct.Collection.html#method.find_one) returns a `Result<Option<Document>>`. Since your patterns only match on the `Result` part, you get the inner `Option`. One solution is to use some more precise patterns:

```
let doc = match db.media.find_one(Some(doc! { "id": id }), None) {
    Ok(Some(c)) => c,
    Ok(None) => {
        println!("Nothing found");
        return;
    }
    Err(e) => {
        println!("An error occurred: {:?}", e);
        return;
    }
};
```